# How to use split a string after a certain length?

Tags: java

I want to split a string after a certain length.

Let's say we have a string of "message"

```
Who Framed Roger Rabbit
```

Split like this :

```
"Who Framed" " Roger Rab" "bit"
```

And I want to split when the "message" variable is more than 10.

my current split code :

```
private void sendMessage(String message){

// some other code ..

String dtype = "D";
int length = message.length();
String[] result = message.split("(?>10)");
for (int x=0; x < result.length; x++)
        {
            System.out.println(dtype + "-" + length + "-" + result[x]); // this will also display the strd string
        }
// some other code ..
}
```

Comment: What are you currently getting as output?

Comment: Do you want to split on what the 11th char?. What should be the OP if message is `abcdefghijklmnop`?

Comment: Have a look at [N-gram generation from a sentence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656762/n-gram-generation-from-a-sentence)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2297347/1743880

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar "klmnop"

Comment: @BrandonLaidig currently, the message doesn't split at all

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I wouldn't use `String.split` for this at all:

```
String message = "Who Framed Roger Rabbit";
for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i += 10) {
  System.out.println(message.substring(i, Math.min(i + 10, message.length()));
}
```

---

Addition 2018/5/8:

If you are simply printing the parts of the string, there is a more efficient option, in that it avoids creating the substrings explicitly:

```
PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(System.out);
for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i += 10) {
  w.write(message, i, Math.min(i + 10, message.length());
  w.write(System.lineSeparator());
}   
w.flush();
```

Comment: This should actually be the right way to go. Its both correct and efficient :)

Comment: This works well ! Can u explain how the "message.substring" part works ?

Comment: I don't really know what to say. It gets the substring between the i-th character and the (i+10)-th character of the string, or the end of the string if that comes first.

Comment: Isn't calculating length on each iteration is a bad idea? I don't know if compiler has optimized code somehow.

Comment: @AndyTurner is there any way I can contact you?

Answer (score 4):

I think Andy's solution would be the best in this case, but if you wanted to use a regex and split you could do

```
"Who Framed Roger Rabbit ".split("(?<=\\G.{10})");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex find, rather than a split
something like this: 
`[\w ]{0,10}`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w ]{0,10}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("who framed roger rabbit");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: Why not `".{,10}"`? or `"[\s\S]{,10}"`?

Comment: I assumed it was looking for text, but `.` would work better if it was any char.

Comment: See my comments on Vinod's answer about why it doesn't necessarily match any character.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. Works for any length of message.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String message =  "Who Framed Roger Rab bit";
    if (message.length() > 10) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".{10}|.{1,}$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(message);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }   
    }
}
```

O/ P :

```
Who Framed
 Roger Rab
 bit
```

Comment: It'd skip characters [not matched by `.`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt), though.

Comment: `.` means *anything* :)

Comment: It means "Any character (may or may not match line terminators)", according to the javadoc.

Comment: @AndyTurner - Ah yes. A multiline pattern would do in that case